# Report builder how to filter current month

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

In report builder how to filter a date field to get the current month? 
I'm looking for something equivalent to the Today() function ( that gets you just today values.

Thanks a Lot for your help.

Comment: Please can you add some sample input/output and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually when I use =field.date.value(Today()) I get today date returned. I would like something like that for the current month instade of the current date.